# Neither tablesorter nor dataTables working with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, datatables, tablesorter

I have tried both, tablesorter and datatables in order to get sorting functionalities. With both, I'm able to see the sorting arrows (and filter box, pages... with dataTables; although they don't work neither), and they change, but the data are not sorted.

Here is the ajax (with dataTables it's the same but using 'dataTable' instead of 'tablesorter'.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "search.php",
    data: {data : encrypted.data, salt: enc_salt},
    success: function(enc_response){
        var response = decrypt_cryptojs(enc_response, encrypted.salt);
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        $("#search_result").html(data);

        // Initialise tablesorter
        $('#search_table').tablesorter();
    } 
});
```

I create the table with php:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $message .= "<table id='search_table' class='tablesorter'>
        <thead><tr>
            <th id='search_user'>Usuario</th>
            <th id='search_name'>Nombre</th>
            <th id='search_surnames'>Apelidos</th>
            <th id='search_email'>Correo</th>
            <th id='search_role'>Rol</th>
            <th id='search_access'>Acceso</th>
            <th id='search_center'>Centro</th>
            <th id='search_edit'></th>
            <th id='search_delete'></th>
        </tr></thead>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        // Define $id
        $id = $row[7];

        // Replace space(" ") whith "&#32" to avoid errors inside functions
        $user = str_replace(" ", "&#32", $row[0]);
        $name = str_replace(" ", "&#32", $row[1]);
        $surnames = str_replace(" ", "&#32", $row[2]);
        $center = str_replace(" ", "&#32", $row[6]);

        $message .= "<tbody><tr>
                <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>" .
                "<td>" .
                    "<input type='image' src='../resources/edit.png' id='edit_" . $row[0] . "' class='edit' onclick=edit_user(\"$user\",\"$name\",\"$surnames\",'$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]',\"$center\",'$id') title='Editar'></button>" . 
                "</td>" .
                "<td>" .
                    "<input type='image' src='../resources/delete.png' id='delete_" . $row[0] . "' class='delete' onclick=delete_user('$user','$row[4]') title='Eliminar'></button>" . 
                "</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    $message .= "</tbody></table>";
    $message .= "<div id='modify_panel'></div>";
}
```

And after that:

```
  // Encode the message using json
  $response = json_encode($message);

  // Encrypt the response and send it.
  $enc_response = encrypt_cryptojs($response, $salt);
  echo $enc_response;
```

With datatables I can see message saying that I have an invalid json response.

"#search_result" is in a php file that is included into another php file.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT: I've found the stupid mistake, I was generating several tbodys. If I move the tag outside the while, it works. Sorry.

Comment: What is your search.php response?

Comment: The response is the html code for the table after being encoded and encrypted. Then, it's decrypted and decoded in the ajax success function and what it's inserted into the html it's just the table code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is likely in the encoding and processing of the JSON.

JSON cannot be merely a string. It needs to be wrapped in an array or object, so when you use php `json_encode` make sure it's getting an array

```
// Encode the message using json
$response = json_encode(array($message));
```

> Note: I don't know php that well, so this example might be wrong.

Now in the javascript, make sure to get the data from the first element of the array

```
var data = JSON.parse(response)[0];
```

Now the `data` *should* be ready to be added as HTML.

```
$("#search_result").html(data);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was not the problem. The problem was that I was generating several tbodys, sorry.